# Conditional testing for existence of specific files and file types in zsh

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh, wildcards

I want to check the current directory for the existence of files with extensions of `abc`, `bak` or `tmp`, *or* a file named `tmpout.wrk`. I can't get this (eventually part of a function) to work in zsh. It runs, but fails to detect properly.

```
if [[ -f *.(abc|bak|tmp) || -f tmpout.wrk ]]; then 
    echo 'true'; 
else 
    echo 'false'; 
fi
```

Comment: Do you want to test if they exists? Or that all (any?) of them are regular files as your `-f` suggests (after or before symlink resolution)?

Comment: Hi @StéphaneChazelas, good point - looking for existance of any type of file or reference to one. That implies instead of `-f` I should use `-a` or `-e` (unclear on the difference)? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR

```
set -o extendedglob
if [[ -n *.(abc|bak|tmp)(#qN) || -f tmpout.wrk ]]; then
```

Otherwise, via some testing,

```
% [[ -f /etc/passwd ]] && echo yea
yea
% echo /etc/passw?
/etc/passwd
% [[ -f /etc/passw? ]] && echo yea
%
```

Okay, what is `zsh` doing here?

```
% set -x
% [[ -f /etc/passw? ]] && echo yes
+zsh:13> [[ -f '/etc/passw?' ]]
%
```

Them single quotes sure aren't going to glob nothing. Let's search on `[[` in `man zshall` ... and then search on `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` ... ah here's something about filename generation:

```
   Filename  generation is not performed on any form of argument to condi-
   tions.  However, it can be forced in any case where normal shell expan-
   sion  is  valid and when the option EXTENDED_GLOB is in effect by using
   an explicit glob qualifier of the form (#q) at the end of  the  string.
   A  normal  glob qualifier expression may appear between the `q' and the
   closing parenthesis; if none  appears  the  expression  has  no  effect
   beyond causing filename generation.  The results of filename generation
   are joined together to form a single word, as with the results of other
   forms of expansion.

   This  special  use of filename generation is only available with the [[
   syntax.  If the condition occurs within the [ or test builtin  commands
   then  globbing  occurs instead as part of normal command line expansion
   before the condition is evaluated.  In this case it may generate multi-
   ple words which are likely to confuse the syntax of the test command.

   For example,

          [[ -n file*(#qN) ]]

   produces  status  zero if and only if there is at least one file in the
   current directory beginning with the string `file'.  The globbing qual-
   ifier  N  ensures  that the expression is empty if there is no matching
   file.
```

So with this in mind,

```
% [[ -f /etc/passw?(#q) ]] && echo yes
+zsh:14> [[ -f /etc/passwd ]]
+zsh:14> echo yes
yes
% exec zsh -l
```

And to your case, accounting for the case where there may be no files:

```
% mkdir dir
% cd dir
% touch blah.foo
% [[ -f *.(foo|bar|baz)(#q) ]] && echo yea
yea
% rm blah.foo
% [[ -f *.(foo|bar|baz)(#q) ]] && echo yea
zsh: no matches found: *.(foo|bar|baz)(#q)
% [[ -f *.(foo|bar|baz)(#qN) ]] && echo yea
% touch a.foo b.foo
% [[ -f *.(foo|bar|baz)(#qN) ]] && echo yea
% [[ -n *.(foo|bar|baz)(#qN) ]] && echo yea
yea
%
```

(though with `-n` we only check that the globs match, not that the corresponding files are regular files).

Comment: Though, since "The results of filename generation are joined together to form a single word", `-f` doesn't work if there's more than one file. Using `-n` and checking the type with a glob qualifier might work? (Well, there the `-n` was in the quote, too)

Answer (score 6):

To test that the glob returns at least one file, you can do:

```
if ()(($#)) (*.(abc|bak|tmp)|tmpout.wrk)(NY1); then
  echo true
else
  echo false
fi
```

To check that at least one of them is a regular file after symlink resolution, add the `-.`  glob qualifier:

```sh
if ()(($#)) (*.(abc|bak|tmp)|tmpout.wrk)(NY1-.); then
  echo true
else
  echo false
fi
```

- `()(($#))` is an anonymous functions to which we pass the result of the globs. The body of that function (`(($#))`) just tests that the number of arguments in non-zero.
- `N` as a glob qualifier turns on `nullglob` for that glob (makes the glob expand to nothing when it doesn't match any file)
- `Y1` limits the expansion to at most one file. It's a performance optimization.
- `-` makes the next glob qualifier be considered *after* symlink resolution.
- `.` considers regular files only (so here regular files or symlinks eventually resolving to a regular file, like the `[ -f file ]` command does).