# Find recursively minimum one *.flac file, if no *.cue file in same dir print directory name

Tags: zsh

I need help doing a search for folder(s) with minimum one `*.flac`-file, but only prints the folder name(s) if there is NOT a `*.cue`-file(s) in the same folder.

Is there echo, find, grep, ls, perl, script command etc. that will work for this?

I'm using zsh in a macOS terminal... thank you!

Comment: That's not a job for a single command, but for a short script. How far have you've gotten? I'd rather we work based on your approach (being something you understand!) than invent something "of our own" (being something you might not understand!).

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that with zsh globs alone:

```
has() ()(($#)) $REPLY/?*.$1(NDY1)
print -rC1 -- **/*(NDFe['has flac && ! has cue'])
```

Remove the `D`s if you want to ignore the hidden files/dirs. Then you can also remove the `?` which we use to make sure a hidden file called `.flac` is seen as a hidden file with no extension rather than a flac file with an empty root name.

See for instance [Conditional testing for existence of specific files and file types in zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/407827) for more details on the kind of construct used here.

You could extend it to:

```
has_at_least() ()(($# >= $1)) $REPLY/?*.$2(NDY$1)
print -rC1 -- **/*(NDFe['has_at_least 3 flac && ! has_at_least 1 cue'])
```

For dirs with at least 3 `flac` files and no `cue` files.

Or:

```
has_from_to() ()(($# >= $1 && $# <= $2)) $REPLY/?*.$3(ND)
print -rC1 -- **/*(NDFe['has_from_to 1 inf flac && has_from_to 0 0 cue'])
```

Or get real fancy and do something like:

```
has() {
  local -A minmax=("$@") count
  local file ext n=${#minmax}
  for file ($REPLY/?*.*(ND)) (( ++count[\$file:e] ))
  for ext ("${(k@)minmax}")
    (( count[\$ext] >= ${minmax[$ext]%-*} &&
       count[\$ext] <= ${minmax[$ext]#*-} &&
       n-- ))
  (( n == 0 ))
}

print -rC1 -- **/*(NDFe['has flac 1-inf txt 2-6 cue 0-0'])
```

For directories with at least 1 `flac`s, 2 to 6 `txt`s and no `cue`